# Swagger UI: How to provide API-Version in Accept-Header for Requests via UI

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a .NET 6 Web API that uses Swashbuckle (6.3.1) to generate documentation and also to provide a UI for testing purposes. The API uses the "Accept-Header"/"Content-Negotiation" method for versioning.

The service itself, including versioning, is working fine.

My first problem is that Swagger UI seems to ignore any hint to the MIME-Type in the Annotations (except for the one in [SwaggerRespone]). My understanding is that one should rather use [ProducesResponseType] instead of [SwaggerRespone].

My second problem is that, even when the MIME-Types are considered, I have to append the Version-part at every single method (as overriding the "accept" header in the code is not possible, as described in https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.2.md#user-content-parametername).

When using [SwaggerResponse] on a method, Swagger UI works as expected:

```
[SwaggerResponse( StatusCodes.Status200OK, ContentTypes = new string[] { "text/plain;api-version=2" } )]
public IActionResult GetHello()
{
    return Ok( "Hello!" );
}
```

[image: content type dropdown with SwaggerResponse]

[image: accept header in curl]

But with [ProducesResponseType], Swagger UI ignores the content type:

```
[ProducesResponseType( typeof( string ), StatusCodes.Status200OK, "text/plain;api-version=2" )]
public IActionResult GetHello()
{
    return Ok( "Hello!" );
}
```

[image: missing content type]

Is there a way to make Swagger UI consider the version info as part of the accept header without the Swagger-specific annotation? Or is it "Ok" to use SwaggerResponse instead of ProducesResponseType? It feels wrong to deviate from best practice just to make Swagger UI happy, which is only relevant during development...

Also, is there any way to append the version info to the content type globally, or at least only once for every controller? It also feels weird to define this at every method, as I have 1 controller per version, and the generated YAML becomes more and more redundant...